# Error encounter while integrating Oauth in Orchard RSS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchard-modules

I am getting this error after install Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth from nuget manager. and site keep on loading

> Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager - (null) - Error loading extension 'HttpAuth' [(null)]
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> File name: 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: what version did you install?

Comment: looks like the required version is 3.0.0.0 but installed is of a different version

Comment: You probably had another version installed or the other version is being copied over from another project. Check the version on the compiled directory and the versions installed on all the projects of the solution.

Comment: thank you very much for quick reply.Still I am facing same issue.I have same version in my project.
could you please help me how can I fixed it